# How can we analyze electronic capacitors in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, voltage

Two capacitors are in series, such as in this circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit]

When doing a circuit analysis, how can we describe the voltages and charges across the two capacitors?

Comment: Your question looks fine to me, but in any case - please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Charge:** If you consider the inner plates of the two capacitors together with the wire that connects them, you get a single isolated conductor:

  > [image]

  Since there is essentially zero charge in the wire itself, and the conductor is neutral, you need the charges on the two plates to be opposite. This means that, under the most reasonable sign convention for how the capacitors are wired (i.e., with both the same way), the charges are equal:
  $$
     Q_1=Q_2.
     $$
- **Voltage:** The voltage is the line integral of the electric field, which takes a nonzero value in the spaces between the capacitor plates, and a negligible value within the wires.

  > [image]

  This means that voltage is additive over the capacitors:
  $$
     V = V_1 + V_2.
     $$